# Как добавить класс блоку

Tags: javascript, html, css

подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно добавить класс блоку. есть иконка1 с классом "click_link", при нажатии на которую у нее появляется класс "active". нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии на эту иконку, если у нее есть класс active, то блоку c классом "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1 open" присваивался тоже класс active. потом при нажатии на другую иконку у иконки1 исчезает класс active и у блока тоже исчезал класс active.
пытался так, но что то не работает как надо. `var element = document.querySelector('.click_link');
var block = document.querySelector('.open');

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.click_link');
var block = document.querySelector('.open');

element.onclick() = function() {
    if (element.classList.contains("active"))
        block.classList.toggle('.active');
    else block.classList.remove('.active');
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не по теме: лучше использовать `element.addEventListener('click',handle)` вместо `element.onclick()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.click_link');
const block = document.querySelector('.open');

elements.forEach((element) =>
{
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) =>
    {
        const isActive = event.target.classList.contains('active');

        block.classList.toggle('active', isActive);
    });
});
```

```css
.click_link
{
  display: block;
}

.open
{
  display: none;
}

.open.active
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="click_link">icon 1</button>
<button class="click_link active">icon 2 (с классом active)</button>
<button class="click_link">icon 3</button>

<div class="open">
  Block
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем корректно такой код работает. я уже пробовал такой вариант только в другом исполнении. получается один раз на иконку кликаешь у блока появляется класс active. и пока снова не кликнешь на эту же иконку он не исчезает. а надо кликнул на иконку с данным классом у блока появился класс у блока, кликнул на другую иконку у блока удалился класс active

Comment: наверное здесь двойную проверку сделать надо

Comment: Честно, не совсем тогда понимаю задачу. Получается "кнопки" по которым нужно кликать - их две? И одна добавляет класс, другая убирает?

Comment: Или.. Если у кнопки если есть класс, то у блока переключается состояние. А если нет класса, то всегда уляется?

Comment: их несколько. типа вкладки. так вот по клик по нужной добавляет класс к блоку, клик по другим убирает у блока класс. дело в том что этот блок с классом выше я указал, нужно скрыть мне. именно только при нажатии на нужную иконку.  во всех остальных случаях блок должен быть видимым

Comment: Можете тогда привести больше кода, чтообы было больше понятно? Из вашего примера выбирается лишь один элемент по которому кликаем. По этому мало понимания.

Comment: если у иконки с классом click_link есть класс active то блок скрывается, если нет такого класса блок видимый.

Comment: даже не представляю как сбросить вам код. там столько кода и такая неразбериха после предыдущего дельца.

Comment: var element = document.querySelector('.click_link');
var block = document.querySelector('.open');

element.onclick = function() {
    block.classList.add('active');
}   вот такой код добавляет блоку класс. но кликаю по другой кнопке класс все также присутствует у блока. а надо чтобы убирался

Comment: Отредактировал, так?

Comment: вот смотрите    var element = document.querySelector('.click_link');
var block = document.querySelector('.open');

element.onclick = function() {
    block.classList.add('active');
}

Comment: На блок всегда будет даваться класс "active", при нажатии на "click_link".

Comment: да, но у других кнопок нет класса click link  и при нажатии на них у блока должен удаляться класс active. как это реализовать. я попробую сейчас изображение добавить чтобы нагляднее было

Comment: В вашем коде приведена выборка лишь одной кнопки, по этому такая путаница.

Comment: добавил картинку, может так будет понятнее что мне нужно?

Comment: Обновил. Правильно?

Comment: да то что надо, только почему то на моей странице не работает, не добавляет класс к open

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127109/discussion-between-oliver-patterson-and-nikitasalnikov).